# How to save double datatype value in sqlite in android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am facing problem about sqlite database. i want to save data in database. KEY_LATITUDE and KEY_LONGITUDE get null values from info.getLatitude() and info.getLongitude() respectively. but info.getLongitude() and info.getLatitude() has 12.99999 and 50.9999 respectively.

```
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_EventName = "event_name";
private static final String KEY_Description = "description";
private static final String KEY_Location = "location";
private static final String KEY_Date = "date";
private static final String KEY_Time = "time";
private static  String KEY_LATITUDE ;
private static  String KEY_LONGITUDE ;
```

addinfo function save data into database.

```
    public void addInfo(Event info) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_EventName, info.getEventName());
    values.put(KEY_Location, info.getLocationName());

    values.put(KEY_Description, info.getDescription());
    values.put(KEY_Date, info.getDate());
    values.put(KEY_Time, info.getTime());

    values.put(KEY_LATITUDE, info.getLatitude()); // it return Double
                                                    // value.i.e 12.999999
    values.put(KEY_LONGITUDE, info.getLongitude()); // it return Double
                                                    // value.i.e 12.999999

    db.insert(TABLE_EVENT_DATA, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert your `Double` value to `String`

```
 values.put(KEY_LATITUDE, String.valueOf(info.getLatitude())); 
 values.put(KEY_LONGITUDE, String.valueOf(info.getLongitude()));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize your column name variables:

```
private static  String KEY_LATITUDE ;
private static  String KEY_LONGITUDE ;
```

change to e.g.

```
private static final String KEY_LATITUDE = "latitude";
private static final String KEY_LONGITUDE = "longitude";
```